# Exception in main class in Spring Boot Application

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I am trying to make a simple spring boot application following this tutorial...
https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-maven-project

But getting this error when I finally run it. I have no idea what is going on. I updated the dependencies and then this happened.

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:37)
        at org.apache.log4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:43)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:45)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:66)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
```

And the list goes on and on. 
Please help.

Comment: Let build project manually, you will learn more. Try other simple example, here http://javabycode.com/spring-framework-tutorial/spring-boot-tutorial/spring-boot-freemarker-hello-world-example.html

Comment: @DavidPham Thank you sir! That tutorial seems much better than that my one. :)

Comment: You can click the icon "this comment adds something useful to the post"

Comment: Sir, I still have a problem. Could I have your email id? I asked in that page as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistakenly added slf4j-log4j12 to the application. Log4j replaced by log4j-over-slf4j and slf4j implemented by log4j, so they call [each](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-log4j12/src/main/java/org/slf4j/log4j12/Log4jLoggerFactory.java#L83) [other](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/log4j-over-slf4j/src/main/java/org/apache/log4j/Category.java#L57).

You should get the following [message](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#log4jDelegationLoop) before StackOverflowError:

```
Detected both log4j-over-slf4j.jar AND slf4j-log4j12.jar on the class path, preempting the StackOverflowError.
```